# How many layers can I make in Blender 2.8

Tags: layers

Couldn't find any info on how many layers can Blender 2.8 handle. I need like 70-100 layers and need to know what is the limit of layers amount?

Answer (score 1):

There are no more layers in Blender 2.80. Layers have been replaced by [Collections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/collections/introduction.html#collections)
I have no idea, how many of them you can create (the limit might even be your hardware here), but it is basically as many, as you wish.

If you create a new text block in the Text editor, type:

```
import bpy 

for i in range(1,1000):
    C = bpy.data.collections.new("Collection"+str(i) )
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(C)
```

and then hit Run Script, it will create 1000 empty collections. If you need that many, or if you start to worry about collection amount limitations chances are you are doing something very wrong. Don't worry about them.

Comment: Ah, I was talking about View Layers (in top right corner in Blender)

Comment: It should be same with View Layers. As many as you wish.

Comment: But you should not normally have 100s of them - it might not be convenient to work with. Are you sure it's the best way to do what you want to do? It may be worthwhile for you to describe your situation, context and goals in more detail in a separate question and ask how it would be most efficient to achieve those goals. You might find some more convenient, easier, more efficient workflows for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing a 2d animation and parts of some objects have to be hidden behind other objects. For example, iris of a character is a circle object and it has to be shown only partially when character narrows eyes. The best solution I tried is to make those objects on separate view layers and use Alpha Over node in compositor, so alpha of an eye object cuts some parts of an iris.

Comment: You can do 2D animation in 3D space as well so the 2D shapes cover each other. That sounds easier to me...

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty simple, but I'm doing it an Adobe AE style with lots of masking, so there is no need to change shape of an object each time.